# Retrieve object from NSArray by specifying class name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsobject

**The task:**

Return an object from an `NSArray` that's instance of the class who's name is given as parameter to the function.

Right now I have this function:

```
+ (id)objectOfType:(NSString *)name fromArray:(NSArray *)array
{
   for (NSObject* instance in array)
   {
      if ([instance.className isEqualToString:name])
         return instance;
   }       
   return nil;
}
```

However, given that I can transform an array of objects into an array of class names of the objects with this simple method call on an `NSArray`

```
[array valueForKeyPath:@"className"]
```

shouldn't there also be a more concise way to retrieve the object with the specified class name..?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. An array is a sorted list and the current implementation is returning the first match. There could of course be more. It could be done based on sets with a predicate filter but that would return a subset or subarray of all matches. Are you always looking for the first match or all?

Comment: Any match at all (as in the code sample) would do - cheers

Comment: In that case I think your implementation is fit for purpose. I think creating and parsing predicates is most likely far slower than the above approach, at least for reasonably sized arrays (a few hundred objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a concise method, using `NSPredicate` and array filtering.

```
+ (id)objectOfType:(NSString *)name fromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    return [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class == %@", NSClassFromString(name)]].lastObject;
}
```

Comment: I guess that'll make for a nice category solving the task in a pretty concise way - cheers!